# $ rails server... undefined method `gem' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to Rails trying to complete this tutorial, but I can;t even get started.
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#sec-rails_server

I am at Step 1.2.5

I am supposed to start the server using: $ rails server

I'm getting this error whenever I try to run any rails command.

```
localhost:first_app home$ rails server
/usr/bin/rails:22: undefined method `gem' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

Running rails commands used to work, because I had completed other tutorials from other books in the past. However, somewhere along the steps in this tutorial something was messed up.

Is it possible that editing my bash_profile caused this?

My bash_profile looks like this now:

```
export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:"$PATH"
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # This loads RVM into a shell session.
```

I added this line to it: **export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:"$PATH"** after following directions in step **Listing 1.1. Creating a gem configuration file.**

I'm not sure if this helps, but If I type:

```
$ which rails
```

I get:

```
/Users/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin/rails
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

typing

```
$  rvm use 1.9.3@rails3tutorial2ndEd --create --default.
```

allowed me to continue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed gem?  type:

```
which gem
```

and see what you get. If you don't have gem or the wrong version, follow these instructions: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#sec-install_rubygems

Comment: If I type **which gem**, I get:
**/usr/bin/gem**. In the instructions it says, *"In fact, if you have installed RVM, you already have RubyGems, since RVM includes it automatically."* I have RVM installed. Anyway, I'll follow those instructions.

Comment: @frandroid... If I follow those instructions, when I type **ruby setup.rb** I get: **ruby: No such file or directory -- setup.rb (LoadError)**

Comment: @frandroid... Ok, Think I figured something out, but I have no idea what I am doing so I don't know if it is the right thing to do. Apparently I need to open a new shell window and type **rvm use 1.9.3@rails3tutorial2ndEd --create --default**. After that I am able to start the server in the 2nd shell window with the **$rails server** command. Man, this stuff is confusing to a newbie.

Comment: I found that most problems I had with the tutorial were when I accidentally skipped a step. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem under ubuntu. I fixed it by changing gnome-terminal settings https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal